# How to filter in query nestjs

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have problem , how to filter in query when user input start_date and end_date

```
const queryA = this.aRepository.query(`
    select
    time_series.time,
    time_series.time + interval '4 hours' - interval '1 sec',
    (
        select
            count(*)
        from
            a
        where
            date_part('hour', created_at) between date_part('hour', time_series.time)
            and date_part(
                'hour',
                time_series.time + interval '4 hours' - interval '1 sec'
            )
    )
    from
    (
        select
            generate_series(
                '2020-01-01 00:00' :: timestamp,
                '2020-01-01 23:59',
                '4 hours'
            ) as time
    ) time_series;
    `);
```

If user input start_date and end_date I don't know how to use with this query

Answer (score 0):

Put parameters in the query function like this

```
const queryA = this.aRepository.query(`select * from table where a = $1`, ['param1'])
```